# How long does it take to catch a rabbit?

Tags: python

> There is a long tunnel. Two people walk from both sides of the tunnel.
> One person places the rabbit. The rabbit runs in one direction, and
> when it meets the other person, it makes a U-turn and runs in the
> opposite direction. If you run again and meet the person on the other
> side, you will make a U-turn again. The rabbit runs until one person
> catches the rabbit.
>
> How long does it take to catch a rabbit? How many times did the rabbit
> make a U-turn? What is the total distance traveled before the rabbit
> was caught?

This is my code

```
Tlength = int(input("Enter tunnel length: "))       
Pspeed = int(input("Enter the speed of two poeple: "))    
Rspeed = int(input("Enter rabbit speed: "))      
Ptime = Tlength / Pspeed    #Ptime = the time a person passed through the tunnel 
Pdist = Pspeed * Ptime      #Pdist = where two people pass through a tunnel                     
Rtime = Tlength / Rspeed    #Rtime = Time when the rabbit meets a person and makes a U-turn
Rdist = Rspeed * Rtime     #Rdist = distance with rabbit
Rreturn = 0                                        

def Rcatch():
    while Pdist - Rdist <= 0:
        if Rcatch:
            Rreturn += 1
        elif Pdist - Rdist <= 0:
            Rreturn += 1
        elif Pdist - Rdist <= 0:
            Rreturn += 1
        else:
            print("The number of U-turns the rabbit", Rreturn)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  In what way does your code not work as expected?  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a math question or physics question, in fact this exact problem has been answered many times on the math stack exchange. Nonetheless, here's the solution:

Everything can be solved using the velocity equation: `v = d/t`

> How long does it take to catch the rabbit?

Assuming you "catch" the rabbit once both people meet:

```py
# t = d/v
# where d = length of tunnel
# and v = combined speed of both people
time_to_catch_rabbit = Tlength / (2*Pspeed)
```

> What is the total distance traveled before the rabbit was caught?

```py
# d = t*v
# where t = time to catch rabbit
# and v = speed of the rabbit
total_distance_travelled_by_rabbit = time_to_catch_rabbit * Rspeed
```

> How many times did the rabbit make a U-turn?

This is a trick question, the number of U-turns is infinite. If you have some trouble understanding this intuitively, there's another way you can solve with problem with an [infinite geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1003043) where it's more obvious.